# How to type emojis in node.js puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, special-characters, puppeteer, emoji

How would I accomplish this? I’m looking to do something like

```
const xpath = page.$x(‘thexpath’)

xpath[0].type(fireemoji)
```

and have the fire emoji show up on the page. Is there an npm module for this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just copy and paste the emoji directly in there like so

```
xpath[0].type();
```

if you look [here](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1096) puppeteer did have some emoji issues but it seems as if it was fixed in [this release](https://github.com/LarenDorr/puppeteer/commit/d90c90f605be351f26608584c93de0135443aa4c)

so also make sure you have the most recent version of puppeteer installed

this code is taken directly from a puppeteer unit test

```
await page.type('textarea', ' Tokyo street Japan ');
```

so make sure you are implementing `.type()` correctly

Comment: Do you have the most recent version of puppeteer installed?